# Java: How to write csv file from ArrayList

Tags: java, file, csv

I have an ArrayList (actually an ArrayList of ArrayLists), each with ints, doubles, and Strings. I would like to write these to a csv file.

It seems that `PrintWriter` requires the data to be a `CharSequence`. Alternatively, when I try to use the `write()` function of `BufferedWriter`, it requires that I specify the type, e.g. `int` or `String`.

Is there a way I can write different types to a csv file? If possible, I would prefer to avoid 3rd-party utilities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A CSV file doesn't care what the value types are, so you should just write all of your data as strings.  For the non-string values, this is as simple as

```
printWriter.write("" + <integer or float variable>);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert each type that you want to output into a String representation before hand.  If it is a class of your own you are trying to convert to a String create a `public String toString()` method for it which will automatically be called when appending to a string or passing to anything that requires a String.

Answer (score 0):

Use String.valueof(elementList) before writing to convert each value in String ?